# How to check if the call to another contract returned successfully?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I want to call contract A in contract B, like this:

```
contract  A{
    uint 256 a;
    function set(uint _a){ 
           require(a > 100);
           a = _a;

    }

}

contract B{
   function callA(){
   A a = A(the_addr_of_A);
   a.set(100);
   }
}
```

But how can I ensure `a.set(100);` is done correctly?

Since I have a require statement `require(a > 100)` in contract A, `a.set(100)` will not work, can contract B notice that?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, because `B` is calling `A`'s function `a`. The whole transaction will revert as a result of this.

If you don't want the whole transaction to revert, you'll have to use `address.call` like in contract C below.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract  A{
    uint256 a;
    function set(uint _a) public { 
        require(_a > 100);
        a = _a;
    }

}

contract C {
    function callA(A _a, uint256 _value) public {
        bool success = address(_a).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("set(uint256)", _value));
        emit ACalled(success);
    }

    event ACalled(bool success);
}
```

Please note that you had a couple of typos in your code.

First deploy `A` using remix or something, then deploy `C`. When both are deployed, call `C.callA`. First with value 100, then with value 101. You'll notice the difference in the transaction logs. Success will be `false` with 100, but `true` with 101.

**Be careful using address.call**

Make sure only addresses of contracts you trust are called.

Comment: Thakn you very much!

Comment: At least in Solidity 0.8.10, I think you need `(bool success,) = address(_a).call(...);`, because `call` returns two values. (The comma ignores the second value.)